# How to retrieve column name and its value from cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Is there any way to get each column name and column value of each row using cursor. 
As below, i have a Cursor c loop through each row of table T

```
 FOR c IN (SELECT * T)  
 LOOP
     --Something like dbms_output.put_line(c.columname : c.columnvalue); 
 END LOOP
```

P/s:Sorry my bad english. English is not my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the DBMS_SQL package instead of a simple FOR loop cursor.  It's quite complex, but luckily [Tom Kyte has already done all the work here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1035431863958#14442395195806)